# Волнистая граница между NestedScrollView и AppBarLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

Если привязать `NestedScrollView` к `CollapsingToolbarLayout` то они не могут быть разделимы между собой. Но проблема в том, что если вверх `NestedScrollView` установить `View` не являющейся прямоугольником, к примеру [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtV3w.png) то происходит вот такой [разрыв](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K0MR.png). По задумке должно выглядеть [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qen4Z.png). Если же растянуть вниз `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, то этот `View` так же будет сдвигаться, но это не должно происходить. [Видео проблемы.](https://youtu.be/rheF1sTkIG0)

Пример кода:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/cyan"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <!-- content of AppBarLayout-->

            </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
      app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <!-- content of NestedScrollView -->

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: лично для меня недостаточно информации, ни по xml т.к. корневого вью не видно, да и в принципе отношений. Так и желаемого поведения.  что-то уезжает, что-то не должно. Попробуйте полнее описать проблему и цель. Возможно поэтому нет предложений по решению.

Comment: Я добавил корневой `view`. Также записал короткое видео, демонстрирующее проблему. На нем видно резкое появление `view`.

Comment: т.е. проблема в том, что вью с волнистым бэком появляется в конце, а не выезжает во время скрола?

Comment: Да, она вообще должна быть статичной и никуда не двигаться. Быть единым элементом с белым фоном.

Comment: если ваша цель сделать волнистую границу, то просто сделайте эту вью частью выезжающего бара

Comment: Я пробовал так делать, но в таком случае NestedScrollView наползает на это view и не очень красиво получается. Совсем не так, как задумано

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/motion-layout-and-motion-scene-ecd88e3ad499 вдруг поможет, готового решения не могу дать

Comment: Попробовал сделать. Увы, для таких целей он не подходит, благодарю за предложение.